# How to avoid creating blogger account error?

Tags: blogger

I want to create a blogger account when I press to create account and than select email its just gets me back to home page like I did nothing and I don't understand what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it after clearing cache and cookies in your browser or in "Incognito" mode or try also with another browser.

Comment: This question was so easy and basic